# PayPal email confirmation

Tags: html, css, node.js, reactjs, paypal

Currently I am trying to implement API for PAY-PAL. So basically, there is a form and user will input their email address on the textbox and that will check if the email that user inputted is valid or not. So pretty much it is verifying if email exist or not. I have created the paypal developer account and searched through google to see if i can get any idea but it did not really helped me much. Can anyone tell me where I should start first? Also, there were something called adaptive accounts on paypal website but not sure if that is the correct one...

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive Accounts is deprecated and not available.

To verify that an email corresponds to a PayPal account, you need to integrate Connect with PayPal: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/

To integrate a PayPal Checkout that will send the payment to a particular email address, you can set a custom payee object to direct the payment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/